# How do I loot a chest on top of a teleportation trap?

Tags: nethack

Given that I don't have magic resistance yet, and walking on to the chest always teleports me away, is there a way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried `#untrap`ping?

Comment: @badp You can't untrap a teleport trap. The only way to remove it would be to, say, dig a pit under it and then fill up the pit. But doing so requires standing on the teleport trap to begin with.

Comment: @Grace: Well, if you just happened to have a spare [drum of earthquake](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Drum_of_earthquake), you could use it to create pits around you.  (Alas, breaking a wand of digging won't work: it's specifically coded not to affect squares with existing traps.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A general point is to move the item off of the trap, typically by kicking. A chest, however, has a special kick interaction, so even with *kicking boots*, you can't move the chest off of the trap. If you have a *wand of teleportation* or know the spell *teleport away*, you can teleport the chest off of the trap, and then hunt down where it lands. As long as it doesn't end up on another teleportation trap, you're home free!

Absent of having a means of teleportation, however, the only other way to get it is indeed to have Magic Resistance such as from a *cloak of magic resistance*. Teleport control will not let you land on a teleport trap, whether you teleport from elsewhere or from the trap itself.

Comment: Ok, I didn't have any of those options. Instead I just repeatedly walked on to it, and eventually (around the 10th time) I got the message `You escape a teleportation trap.`, which allowed me to remain on the square. It's been I while since I last played, so I had forgotten this could happen. =)

Comment: Teleport control will, however, let you simply cancel the teleportation from the trap itself by hitting escape.

Answer (score -1):

Enabling autopickup (shift @/2) will allow you to pick items up before activating traps/portals or falling through holes if you are strong enough to lift them.